# C++ output Unicode in variable

Tags: c++, unicode, unicode-string

I'm trying to output a string containing unicode characters, which is received with a `curl` call. Therefore, I'm looking for something similar to `u8` and `L` options for literal strings, but than applicable for variables. E.g.:

```
const char *s  = u8"\u0444";
```

However, since I have a string containing unicode characters, such as:

```
mit freundlichen Grüßen
```

When I want to print this string with:

```
cout << UnicodeString << endl;
```

it outputs:

```
mit freundlichen Gr??en
```

When I use `wcout`, it returns me:

```
mit freundlichen Gren
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the correct output. I return the output with [RapidJSON](http://rapidjson.org), which returns the string as:

```
mit freundlichen Gr��en
```

***Important to note, the application is a CGI running on Ubuntu, replying on browser requests***

Comment: `std::wcout`, although that perhaps just kicks the encoding conundrum further down the road.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I have already tried using wcout, this results in: `mit freundlichen Gren`

Comment: You need to convert the string from its current encoding (UTF-8 maybe) to the encoding supported by your output device (no idea what that is). There's no quick solution, you have to do some work.

Comment: @john, my output device as in the receiver of the request? I guess it’s also UTF8 actually..?

Comment: @ThomasvanHesteren print out the byte values of your string, and post them here. That will tell what encoding your string is using. If your output device supports UTF-8 and you are seeing ?? in the output that kind of indicates that your string isn't UTF-8. Somhow there's some sort of conversion that needs to happen, first task is to work out exactly what that is.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Is `cout << u8"\u0444"` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system the following produces the correct output. Try it on your system.  I am confident that it will produce similar results.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="mit freundlichen Grüßen";
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If it is ok, then this points to the  web transfer not being 8-bit clean.

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, what I would suggest is using **Unicode UTF-16** at the Windows boundary.

It seems to me that on Windows with Visual C++ (at least up to VS2015) `std::cout` *cannot* output UTF-8-encoded-text, but **`std::wcout`** correctly outputs **UTF-16**-encoded text.

This compilable code snippet correctly outputs your string containing German characters:

```
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <io.h>  
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    // ü : U+00FC
    // ß : U+00DF
    const wchar_t * text = L"mit freundlichen Gr\u00FC\u00DFen";

    std::wcout << text << L'\n';
}
```

Note the use of a **UTF-16-encoded** `wchar_t` string.

[image]

---

On a more general note, I would suggest you using the **UTF-8 encoding** (and for example storing text in `std::string`s) in your *cross-platform* C++ portions of code, and convert to **UTF-16-encoded** text at the *Windows* boundary.

To convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 you can use Windows APIs like `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`. These are C APIs, that can be safely and conveniently wrapped in C++ code (more details can be found in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt763237), and you can find [compilable C++ code here on GitHub](https://github.com/GiovanniDicanio/UnicodeConversions)).

Answer (score 0):

> containing unicode characters

You forgot to specify *which* unicode encoding does the string contain. There is the "narrow" UTF-8, which can be stored in a `std::string` and printed using `std::cout`, as well as wider variants, which can't. It is crucial to know which encoding you're dealing with. For the remainder of my answer, I'm going to assume you want to use UTF-8.

---

> When I want to print this string with:
>
> ```
> cout << UnicodeString << endl;
> ```

EDIT:

> Important to note, the application is a CGI running on Ubuntu, replying on browser requests

The concerns here are slightly different from printing onto a terminal.

1. You need to set the `Content-Type` response header appropriately or else the client cannot know how to interpret the response. For example `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`.
2. You still need to make sure that the source string is in fact the correct encoding corresponding to the header. See the old answer below for overview.
3. The browser has to support the encoding. Most modern browsers have had support for UTF-8 a long time now.

---

Answer regarding printing to terminal:

Assuming that

1. `UnicodeString` indeed contains an UTF-8 encoded string
2. and that the terminal uses UTF-8 encoding
3. and the font that the terminal uses has the graphemes that you use

the above should work.

> it outputs:
>
> ```
> mit freundlichen Gr??en
> ```

Then it appears that at least one of the above assumptions don't hold.

Whether 1. is true, you can verify by inspecting the numeric value of each code unit separately and comparing it to what you would expect of UTF-8. If 1. isn't true, then you need to figure out what encoding does the string actually use, and either convert the encoding, or configure the terminal to use that encoding.

2. The terminal typically, but not necessarily, uses the system native encoding. The first step of figuring out what encoding your terminal / system uses is to figure out what terminal / system you are using in the first place. The details are probably in a manual.

   If the terminal *doesn't* use UTF-8, then you need to convert the UFT-8 string within your program into the character encoding that the terminal does use - unless that encoding doesn't have the graphemes that you want to print. Unfortunately, the standard library doesn't provide arbitrary character encoding conversion support (there is some support for converting between narrow and wide unicode, but even that support is deprecated). You can find the unicode standard [here](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/), although I would like to point out that using an existing conversion implementation can save a lot of work.

   In the case the character encoding of the terminal doesn't have the needed grapehemes - or if you don't want to implement encoding conversion - is to re-configure the terminal to use UTF-8. If the terminal / system can be configured to use UTF-8, there should be details in the manual.
3. You should be able to test if the font itself has the required graphemes simply by typing the characters into the terminal and see if they show as they should - although, this test will also fail if the terminal encoding does not have the graphemes, so check that first. Manual of your terminal should explain how to change the font, should it be necessary. That said, I would expect `üß` to exist in most fonts.

Comment: The code is a CGI, outputting in JSON to the browser sending the request